# How to create a dialogue box pointing to a view above this box?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I want to show a popup like this right below this "pages icon". The "pages icon" is added to the stack view hence it's position is dynamic.

Comment: Hint: popoverPresentationController

Answer (score 0):

The position of the "pages icon" doesn't matter. When we create a popover, we can set a `sourceView`. Set the view that containing the "pages icon" as the `sourceView` of your popover and your popover will always be attached to this view. Also set `permittedArrowDirections` as `.up` so the popover will always appear below the view.

Please find below example in Playground

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let mainViewController = MainViewController()

let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)))
stackView.axis = .horizontal

let button = UIButton()
button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "doc.on.doc.fill"), for: .normal)
button.addTarget(mainViewController, action: #selector(mainViewController.showPopover(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
mainViewController.view.addSubview(stackView)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mainViewController

class MainViewController : UIViewController {
    @objc func showPopover(_ sender: UIButton){
        let popoverController = PopoverController()
        popoverController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.up]
        popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        popoverController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)
        mainViewController.present(popoverController, animated: true)
    }
}

class PopoverController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)))
        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have successfully done that. Thanks El Tomato for the hint

```
 private func showPopup() {
    guard let controller = PopupController.loadViewController() else {
        return
    }
    
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    let popController = controller.popoverPresentationController
    popController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
    popController?.delegate = self
    popController?.sourceRect = (self.pickerButton.bounds)
    popController?.sourceView =  self.pickerButton
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In PopupController write this to adjust vc size according to label inside it.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.preferredContentSize = self.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize
    )
}
```